# Prove that $\vec r ~\times \vec a = \vec 0 $ implies $\vec r ~\times \vec v = \vec c $, where $\vec c$ is a constant vector.

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, curves

> A particle of unit mass with position vector $\vec {r(t)}$ at time $t$ is moving in space under the actions of certain forces. Prove that  $\vec r ~\times \vec a = \vec 0 $ implies $\vec r ~\times \vec v = \vec c $, where $\vec c$ is a constant vector.

I know that this question [has already been posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798163/motion-in-a-plane), but the answer only considered the case given $\vec c = \vec 0$. I am not looking for a full on answer but rather a hint...

Can I also use the triple product to prove it for $\vec c \not = \vec 0$ ? Though is use of the triple product for the case $\vec c = \vec 0$ even valid? Wouldn't it give me a normal vector to the plane equal to $\vec 0$ ?

This section of the textbook deals with "The unit tangent, the principal normal, and the osculating plane of a curve"

Comment: ...and what is that $\;\vec v\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio $\vec v$ is velocity and $\vec a$ is acceleration

Comment: "I know that this question has already been posted", can you share?

Comment: @CalvinKhor https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798163/motion-in-a-plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: compute the time derivative of $\vec r\times \vec v$.

Hint 2: If $f'(t)=0$ for all $t$, what can we say about $f$?

Comment: I get $\vec r \times a = $\vec 0$. Am I maybe supposed to use the fact that acceleration lies in the osculating plane (linear combination of a vector parallel to velocity and one perpendicular to it)?

Comment: @JohnArg does Hint 2 help?

Comment: Not really unfortunately. $f$ is constant, but we're already given that $\vec r \times \vec v$ is constant, so we go back to where we were at at first...

Comment: @JohnArg ? That is not what is in your question. Did you ask the correct question? Your assumption is something = 0, you want to prove something is a constant $\vec c$. Wrong?

Comment: Yup, sorry, I'll upvote your answer..... Posted the wrong question. I already solved this one.