# If $\vec r \times v = \vec c$, where $\vec c$ is a constant vector, prove that the motion takes place in a plane.

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, curves

> A particle of unit mass with position vector $\vec {r(t)}$ at time $t$ is moving in space under the actions of certain forces. If $\vec r \times v = \vec c$, where $\vec c$ is a constant vector, prove that the motion takes place in a plane. Consider both $\vec c = \vec 0$ and $\vec c \not = \vec 0$.

I know that this question [has already been posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798163/motion-in-a-plane), but the answer only considered the case given $\vec c = \vec 0$. I am not looking for a full on answer but rather a hint...

Can I also use the triple product to prove it for $\vec c \not = \vec 0$ ? Though is use of the triple product for the case $\vec c = \vec 0$ even valid? Wouldn't it give me a normal vector to the plane equal to $\vec 0$ ?

This section of the textbook deals with "The unit tangent, the principal normal, and the osculating plane of a curve"

Comment: I think the answer given considers the case $\vec c \neq 0$, not $=0$?

Comment: It says that the scalar product of $\vec r$ and $\vec c$ is $0$. That only seems obvious to me if $\vec c= \vec 0$

Comment: Its from the box product that you are trying to use. two equal vectors in box product = 0.

Comment: Didn't know that... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome (have added this explanation to the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the linked answer, for $\vec c\neq \vec 0$, we get $0=\vec r\cdot (\vec r\times \vec v) = \vec r\cdot \vec c$, so the particle moves in the plane $0=\vec r\cdot \vec c$. (The box product is the determinant of the matrix with the 3 vectors as rows. If two rows repeat, the determinant is zero.)

For $\vec c=0$, this means that the velocity and the particle position are parallel. Thus, if there is some $t_0$ such that $\vec r(t_0)\neq \vec 0$, then  $\vec r(t) = \vec r(t_0) \lambda (t)$ for some scalar valued function $\lambda (t)\in\mathbb R$. In particular....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you get $λ(t)$

Comment: @JohnArg Well it is a hint as requested, and not a full answer. Do you know how to solve ODEs of the form $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}(t) = c(t) \vec r(t)$? Maybe you can treat the components of $\vec r$ one by one?